# Gettinng user profile information for OAuth2 JWT

Tags: xamarin, asp.net-core, jwt, google-oauth

I am making an api that accepts social logins from a few services, namely Google.

So far, the mobile app allows the user to log in to google with the OAuth2 flow, and obtains a JWT token. The *first* time I was able to get the profile info from the token (first name, family name, profile pic, etc...). Now, I doesn't contain all of the fields I need.

I remember reading somewhere that google will only send *all* the fields from time to time...

Since I'm in testing, I tend to wipe the user database often and would like to be able to count on the google JWT to re-create the account.

I'd rather use the token than hitting the `userInfo` API. Especially since the JWT is technically secure.

So, is there any sure way to get *all* of the user profile info in the id_token from the google API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an older endpoint, changed to `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth` and everything is ok!

Answer (score 1):

Check the 'scopes' that you define when logging in with Google. Each scope has a type of data that it returns back to the user. Be sure that you're using `scope: 'profile'`" when initializing the Google login. If additional scopes are necessary, use add them to the request as shown in the link below.

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/incremental-auth